# batch convert xml to json Mac

Tags: xml, json, batch-file

This is my first post here so please be forgiving.
I have about 56gb of xml files (trade documents) i need to convert in to json format.
Are there any tools out there that might do this for me?

Comment: You can do it with this xml2json project: https://github.com/hay/xml2json

Comment: You will need to install python if it is not done.

Comment: Hi can you instruct how to perform on multiple files?

Answer (score 0):

**xml2json.js** is a js library for converting xml files to json format, you can craete a small program using this script, or try my online xml to json converter https://xmltojson.tk/ , you can convert multiple xml files in a single click, Very easy to use, created with **xml2json.js**